# Create Alias using another column value

Tags: mysql

I’m  having a bad time trying to create an alias for a table column using a value from another table

Something like this

```
SELECT tb1.name, tb2.value AS tb3.label FROM table_1 AS tb1
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS tb2 ON tb1.id = tb2 table_1_id
LEFT JOIN table_3 AS tb3 ON tb2.table_3_id = tb3.id
```

It should use the var char value from tb3.label as alias to tb2.value
So i can group by tb1.id and not lost all values from tb2

Comment: You can't have a different alias for each row, aliases apply on columns

Comment: 'So i can group by tb1.id and not lost all values from tb2' - Please expand including sample data and desired outcome as text.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add a table to a column alias, and also label is a reserved word as well.

```
SELECT tb1.name, tb2.value AS `label` 
FROM table_1 AS tb1
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS tb2 ON tb1.id = tb2.table_1_id
LEFT JOIN table_3 AS tb3 ON tb2.table_3_id = tb3.id
```

Comment: Label is not a keyword in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-L

Comment: workbench didn't like it

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any problem. I tested the query in MySQL Workbench 8.0.36, without delimiting the word `label`. It shows no error or warning or syntax highlighting on the word `label`. It works fine.